# Converting 1D pandas dataframes to N-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have 5 1D pandas dataframes, that I want to convert to a single numpy array. Each of those 1-D dataframes should be stacked and not appended below the other. The individual 1-D dataframes have the shape (10000 rows × 1 columns).
My code so far,

```
df1=pd.read_csv('/content/samples.csv')
df1=df1.drop(df1.index[0])
df1=df1.drop(df1.columns[[0]],1)
dfraw1=df1.drop(df1.columns[[1]],1)
dfclean1=df1.drop(df1.columns[[0]],1)

df2=pd.read_csv('/content/samples (1).csv')
df2=df2.drop(df2.index[0])
df2=df2.drop(df2.columns[[0]],1)
dfraw2=df2.drop(df2.columns[[1]],1)
dfclean2=df2.drop(df2.columns[[0]],1)

df3=pd.read_csv('/content/samples (2).csv')
df3=df3.drop(df1.index[0])
df3=df3.drop(df3.columns[[0]],1)
dfraw3=df3.drop(df3.columns[[1]],1)
dfclean3=df3.drop(df3.columns[[0]],1)

df4=pd.read_csv('/content/samples (3).csv')
df4=df4.drop(df4.index[0])
df4=df4.drop(df4.columns[[0]],1)
dfraw4=df4.drop(df4.columns[[1]],1)
dfclean4=df4.drop(df4.columns[[0]],1)

df5=pd.read_csv('/content/samples (4).csv')
df5=df5.drop(df5.index[0])
df5=df5.drop(df5.columns[[0]],1)
dfraw5=df5.drop(df5.columns[[1]],1)
dfclean5=df5.drop(df5.columns[[0]],1)

#Appending all the DataFrames into one DataFrame
dfa1=np.dstack((dfraw1, dfraw2)).shape
dfa2=np.dstack((dfraw3, dfraw4)).shape
```

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: what should be the shape of the final dataframe ?

Comment: 10000 rows × 1 columns x 5

Comment: pandas dataframes are for 2 dimensional data

Comment: Then how do I put it into a n-dimensional numpy array?

Comment: So what has happened?  What's `dfa1` etxc?  Do just show code.  I don't like trying to run code in my head.

Comment: Are you sure you mean n-dimensional (with n>2)? As in, a tensor of data? Or do you actually mean just getting a 10_000 x 5 DataFrame? In the latter case, use `pd.concat(..., axis=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], columns = ['a'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], columns = ['b'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], columns = ['c'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], columns = ['d'])
df5 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], columns = ['e'])
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4,df5], axis = 1)
df
```

|  | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 |